# Ask for OJS theme footer

Tags: themes, footer, ojs

Really thank you for pointing as he could not add themewas activated. I would like to ask your opinion if you know how I add a footnote to the style of this website:http://www.methaodos.org/revista-methaodos/index.php/methaodos

My question is, there are modules that you create thisfootnote? Or on the contrary they should be within thetemplate theme?

Thanks again beforehand.

Comment: templates/common/footer.tpl

<div id="divPiePagina">
<p>el contenido del pie de página</p>
</div>
styles/sidebar.css

#divPiePagina p {
font-size: 12px;
float: left;
background-color: blue;
width: 90%;
height: 70px;
margin-top: 200px;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-top: 15px;
line-height: 15pt;
}

Comment: Deputy code I'm using and I can not be equal to the web model indicated .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if I understand your question correctly. If you would like to add a footnote to your OJS, you can co to /index.php/ip/manager/setup/5. There is an option for this.